# Can't Create Platform Application for FCM in AWS SNS using Python SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sns

trying to create a Platform Application for AWS' SNS using Python SDK (boto3)

```
client = session.client('sns')
response = client.create_platform_application(
    Name="firebase",
    Platform='FCM',
    Attributes={
        'PlatformCredential': [FCM_SERVER_KEY]
    }
)
```

Getting back the following error:

```
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterException: An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the CreatePlatformApplication operation: Invalid parameter: Platform Reason: FCM is not supported
```

If I'm creating that in the AWS console it works fine. Is it just a partial boto3 implementation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Platform should be **GCM** and not **FCM** although it is a firebase platform.
So the correct code would be:

```
response = client.create_platform_application(
    Name="firebase",
    Platform='GCM',
    Attributes={
        'PlatformCredential': [FCM_SERVER_KEY]
    }
)
``
```